# How to define parquet schema for ParquetOutputFormat for Hadoop job in java?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, parquet

I have a Hadoop job in java, which has sequence output format:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

I want to use Parquet format instead. I tried to set it in the naive way:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(ParquetOutputFormat.class);
ParquetOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
ParquetOutputFormat.setCompression(job, CompressionCodecName.GZIP);
ParquetOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
```

But when in comes to writing job's result to disk, the bob fails:

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: writeSupportClass should not be null
    at parquet.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:38)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getWriteSupport(ParquetOutputFormat.java:326)
```

It seems, that parquet needs a schema te be set, but I couldn't find ane manual or guide, how to do that in my case. 
My `Reducer` class tries to write down 3 long values on each line by using `org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable` as a key and `org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.EntityEntityWritable` as a value.

**How can I define a schema for that?**

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a "[parquet.hadoop.api.WriteSupport](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/api/WriteSupport.java)" impelementation for your job. 
(ex: "parquet.proto.ProtoWriteSupport" for protoBuf or "parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport" for avro)

```
ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass(job, ProtoWriteSupport.class);
```

when using protoBuf, then specify protobufClass:

```
 ProtoParquetOutputFormat.setProtobufClass(job, your-protobuf-class.class);
```

and when using avro, introduce schema like this:

```
AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, your-avro-object.SCHEMA);
```